# Window management with numpad on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, window, shortcuts

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 now, and used to use Ubuntu 16.04 a long time ago on which I add a GNOME extension, that I don't recall the name, that allows you to use a more powerfull window management tool with keyboards bindings to `Super+NumPadX`where X would be a number from 0 to 9 on your NumPad. 0 hides the current window, 4 and 6 for splitting left/right, 2 and 8 for splitting up and down, 1/3/7 and 9 would put the current window in the corner.

I'd really like to have something similar on my new Ubuntu 22.04, but can't find how to do it

If anybody can help, cool

Thanks to all

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS used the Unity 7 desktop by default; having replaced the GNOME 2 desktop back in Ubuntu 11.04, with Unity 7 being default until Ubuntu 17.10 which was the first release with GNOME 3.  Are you sure you were using GNOME on 16.04?

Comment: @guiverc I'm sure I was using a GNOME extensions for that, and with your good remark I now think that it was Ubuntu 18.04, not 16.04

Answer (score 1):

There may be GNOME Shell Extensions that do what you want (I've never used it, but I've seen others reference [Tactile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4548/tactile/)), but you can also do something similar with GSettings. Here is what I use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-nw "['<Super>KP_7']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-ne "['<Super>KP_9']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-se "['<Super>KP_3']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-sw "['<Super>KP_1']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-n "['<Super>KP_8']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-e "['<Super>KP_6']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-s "['<Super>KP_2']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-w "['<Super>KP_4']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-center  "['<Super>KP_5']"
```

Note that this does not resize the windows. You can use `Alt` + `F8` to manually [resize windows](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-windows-states.html.en).

You can also use `Super` + `Left` / `Super` + `Right` to [half-tile](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-windows-tiled.html.en).

Answer (score 1):

If not already installed, install [Extension Manager](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/05/manage-gnome-extensions-ubuntu-2204/) and afterwards use the *Browse* tab to select `Awesome Tiles`

[image]

<kbd>SuperKP</kbd> in this context refers to pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> and KP = keypress so to centre, for example use <kbd>Super + 0</kbd> on the numeric keypad as in the earlier releases. The other key combinations are as listed.